# what is the purpose of declaring mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have been going through some nodejs/mongoose code and I realised that there are some codes which explicitly define the _id field when trying to store data in mongodb-mongoose.

Example

```
var personSchema = Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});
```

I am aware that documents in Mongodb are by default assigned a unique _id field. Then why would someone still want to define "_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId," what is the advantage of this? I mean, whether they define or not wouldn't it still be there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there is no change between declaring it or not at top schema level.

---

As the [documentation of mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id) says :

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one
>   is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type assigned is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDB's default behavior.

---

Some people may add it in order to make it explicit : the `_id` field exists and it's an `ObjectId`.

---

---

**NOTE** that in a subschema, the `_id` can be disabled using `_id` option

> **option**:
>
> _id Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by
>   default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type
>   assigned is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDB's default behavior.
>   If you don't want an _id added to your schema at all, you may disable
>   it using this option.
>
> You can only use this option on subdocuments. Mongoose can't save a
>   document without knowing its id, so you will get an error if you try
>   to save a document without an _id.

```
// default behavior
var schema = new Schema({ name: String });
var Page = mongoose.model('Page', schema);
var p = new Page({ name: 'mongodb.org' });
console.log(p); // { _id: '50341373e894ad16347efe01', name: 'mongodb.org' }

// disabled _id
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: String }, { _id: false });
var parentSchema = new Schema({ children: [childSchema] });

var Model = mongoose.model('Model', parentSchema);

Model.create({ children: [{ name: 'Luke' }] }, function(error, doc) {
  // doc.children[0]._id will be undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose schema designed to add `_id` field in each created entry either document or subdocument (embedded).

Declaring a `_id` field is only useful in the schema when you want to embed some fields of a model document as subdocument instead of adding a `ref` with the original id otherwise it will add a newly generated `ObjectId` as `_id` in the subdocument schema.